# How to view the end of a tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a TKinter Entry widget to visualize a path. Now, the path string  is actually longer than the widget and after inserting it I can only see the beginning of the path. Since I do this to select a particular file, it would be better to show the end of the path string where the file name is. Is there a way to view the end of the Entry widget?
Thanls

Comment: Please share the code you are trying. Also an example of what you expect would be nice.

Comment: Try finding the corresponding methods by using `help(tk.Entry)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

- the first is to set the cursor towards the end of the string in order to display the filename.
- the other is to set a label that will get the value of the entry and display its entirety.

This example combines both :

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_label(e):
    var.set(entry.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()

    var = tk.StringVar()

    label = tk.Label(root, textvar=var)
    label.pack()

    var.set('this is a very long link with the filename at the end filename.txt')

    entry.insert(0, var.get())

    entry.bind('<Enter>', update_label)
    entry.xview(len(var.get()) - 10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  a lot Reblochon Masque for your answer. The code you added actually led me to an even easier solution, that is the use of the attribute xview_moveto. Indeed, if I use the following code:

```
myEntry.xview_moveto(1)
```

The end of the entry is visualized together with the file name as I needed.